# SQL - Save results from stored procedure to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I cannot change. And it returns a select value (integer).

It insert some values and return the new id - the last line of the stored procedure:

```
SELECT @newID
```

I am using the new ID but I don't want to display that value when I run the stored procedure.

So I use the following:

```
DECLARE @test INT 
EXEC @test = Pr_My_Procedure 'NewGroupName'
SELECT @test
```

This executes successfully, but my variable @test is always = 0 when the actual value created and return for the stored procedure is an actual id number.

Why is my variable is not being assigned?

I have a work around (which is not really what I wanted but it works:

```
1    DECLARE @NewGroupID INT    
2    EXEC Pr_My_Procedure 'NewGroupName'
3    SET @NewGroupID = (SELECT GroupID FROM DB..Groups WHERE GroupName = 'NewGroupName')
```

This works, but when running the stored procedure, I still get the GroupID generated being return on the results (line 2). I don't want to see that.

Is it possible to NOT return that select result from the procedure?

Thanks all for any advise!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do

```
exec @p = StoredProc
```

... you are dealing with the *return value* of the proc, not the result set of the proc. The default return value of a procedure is zero so that if you do not do an explicit RETURN in your procedure, it returns 0.

You can change the procedure to RETURN your ID, or add an output parameter.

```
-- Procedure which RETURNS the ID
create procedure StoredProc_WithReturn
as
    return 10;
go

-- Procedure which uses output parameter instead.
create procedure StoredProc_WithOutput 
@p int output
as
    select @p = 12;
go

-- Now test both ways of returning a value
declare @p int = 0,
        @po int = 0;

exec @p = StoredProc_WithReturn;
select @p;

exec StoredProc_WithOutput @po output;
select @po;
```

Since you cannot change the procedure, you can insert the result set of the procedure into a table, temporary table or table variable like so

```
create procedure StoredProc_WithSelect
as
    select 10;
go

declare @pt table (a int);

insert @pt 
exec StoredProc_WithSelect;
select a from @pt;
```

Comment: Peter, your explanation was great. I've learn from it.... Thank you. Although I cannot change the procedure. I guess I will have to leave the variable assigning as in my initial query. Thanks again. Explanation great!

Comment: There is a solution for that case as well :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see result, you can use `PRINT` instead of `SELECT`. Try this:

```
DECLARE @test INT 
EXEC @test = Pr_My_Procedure 'NewGroupName'
PRINT @test
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I don't want to print the result, I want to assigned the result.